# How to loop through mult level dict or yaml in Ansible 2.7 or 2.8?

Tags: python, ansible

I've found a few ansible looping examples through multi level yaml, but, I can't seem to get down to one more level.

I have a list of machines or vms I'm trying to create on a xenserver pool and I need to pick out hostnames, num of cpus, etc.

```
#Requires ansible dev version 2.8.  2.8 will be release summer 2019.

- hosts: xenservers
  vars:
    Machines:
      Connectors:
        Connector1:
          hostname: CCConn-0001
          num_cpus: 4
          num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 2
          memory_mb: 8192
        Connector2:
          hostname: CCConn-0002
          num_cpus: 4
          num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 2
          memory_mb: 8192
      #Storefronts:
      #  Storefront1:
      #    hostname: SFPrinci-0001
      #    num_cpus: 4
      #    num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 2
      #    memory_mb: 8192

  tasks:
  # - name: Create VMs from a template
  #   xenserver_guest:
  #     hostname: 10.8.47.11
  #     username: 
  #     password: 
  #     validate_certs: no
  #     #folder: /home/testvms
  #     name: '{{Need a hostname here}}'
  #     state: poweredon
  #     template: W2K16_RTM_64_EN_ans
  #     disks:
  #     - size_gb: 100
  #       name: ''
  #       sr: XenRTVol
  #     linked_clone: yes
  #     hardware:
  #       num_cpus: 'Need number of cpus here'
  #       num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 'Need cores per socket here'
  #       memory_mb: 'Need memory here'
  #     cdrom:
  #       type: iso
  #       iso_name: guest-tools.iso
  #     networks:
  #     - name: vlan40
  #     wait_for_ip_address: no
  #   delegate_to: localhost
  #   register: deploy
  #   with_subelements: '{{Machines}}'

  - name:
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.key }} - {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ Machines | dict2items }}"
```

I've been playing around with dict2items, but, I don't know how to get the values I need one level lower.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw away all key names on two levels and iterate over values only:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ Machines | json_query('*.*[]') }}"
```

`json_query` filter uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Python nested dictionary lookups can be done as follows:

```
# Create test dictionary
test_dict = {'level_one': {'level_two': 'test'}}

# Print the nested value
print(test_dict['level_one']['level_two'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess my main issue is translating that syntax into jinja2 or whatever ansible is looking for.